# Calling Stored Procedure at run time in ASP.net

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have created various stored procedures in SQL Server as per my need for reporting purposes. I want to create a single API that reads the name of stored procedure as input and returns the array of the result returned from stored procedure.

To note, the same single method will invoke various stored procedures and return a kind of dynamic anonymous object array in JSON format to my UI.

Is the solution possible using Entity Framework. Not using the ADO.net connection mechanism?

Intention: every time when there is a need of new report I don't need to make new releases of my software. I will just create the stored procedure in backend and add the name of new stored procedure in some table which will be read by my API.

Comment: Entity framework uses ado.net, too. What justifies then your requirement to not to use ado.net?

Comment: I want to stick to the current EF6 and not to use the ADO.net connected/disconnected architecture by writing all custom core db connection classes. Sorry not to put it clearly !!!

Comment: So far, i generated the stored procedure in sql server and when i update my asp.net application the EF will generate the class based on return type of stored procedure and add the method in context class something like "public virtual ObjectResult<ReturnType> StoredProcName(parameters if any) { //calls ExecuteFunction method passing the store procedure name} ------ I want new generic method that can call all stored procedure and return something like List<Object>

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be obtained with [`SqlDataAdapter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter(v=vs.110).aspx) objects. However you cannot do it with Entity Framework as far as I know, just direct `SqlConnection` management.

SqlDataAdapter has [a nice example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_8) of doing so:

```
private static DataSet SelectRows(DataSet dataset, string connectionString,string queryString) 
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
        adapter.Fill(dataset);
        return dataset;
    }
}
```

The resulting DataSet will have one (or more if the sproc returns more) `DataTable` that will contain the execution result.

It is up to you to display it or process it somehow.